# Istio Traffic Shifting not working in Internal communication

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, istio

I deployed Istion on my local Kubernetes cluster running in my Mac. I created this **VirtualService**, **DestinationRule** and **Gateway**.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: code-gateway
  namespace: code
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "gateway.code"

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: codemaster
  namespace: code
spec:
  hosts:
  - master.code
  - codemaster
  gateways:
  - codemaster-gateway
  - code-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: codemaster 
        subset: v1 

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: codemaster-gateway
  namespace: code
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "master.code"


apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: codemaster
  namespace: code
spec:
  host: codemaster
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      tcp:
        maxConnections: 100
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2


- apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Service"
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: "codemaster"
      group: "code"
    name: "codemaster"
    namespace: "code"
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: http-web
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    selector:
      app: "codemaster"
      group: "code"
    type: "ClusterIP"

- apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  kind: "Deployment"
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: "codemaster"
      group: "code"
      env: "production"
    name: "codemaster"
    namespace: "code"
  spec:
    replicas: 2
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: "codemaster"
        group: "code"
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: "codemaster"
          version: "v1"
          group: "code"
          env: "production"
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: "KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE"
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: "metadata.namespace"
          - name: "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL"
            value: "jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/code_master"
          - name: "SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME"
            value: "postgres"
          - name: "SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD"
            value: "postgres"
          image: "kzone/code/codemaster:1.0.0"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          name: "codemaster"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
            name: "http"
            protocol: "TCP"

apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "List"
items:
- apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  kind: "Deployment"
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: "codemaster"
      group: "code"
      env: "canary"
    name: "codemaster-canary"
    namespace: "code"
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: "codemaster"
        group: "code"
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: "codemaster"
          version: "v2"
          group: "code"
          env: "canary"
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: "KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE"
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: "metadata.namespace"
          - name: "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL"
            value: "jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/code_master"
          - name: "SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME"
            value: "postgres"
          - name: "SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD"
            value: "postgres"
          image: "kzone/code/codemaster:1.0.1"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          name: "codemaster"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
            name: "http"
            protocol: "TCP"
```

These are the services running in **code** namespace,

```
codemaster   ClusterIP   10.103.151.80   <none>        80/TCP    18h
gateway      ClusterIP   10.104.154.57   <none>        80/TCP    18h
```

I deployed 2 spring-boot microservices in ton k8s. One is a spring-boot gateway.
These are the pods running in code namespace,

```
codemaster-6cb7b8ddf5-mlpzn          2/2     Running   0          7h3m
codemaster-6cb7b8ddf5-sgzt8          2/2     Running   0          7h3m
codemaster-canary-756697d9c8-22qb2   2/2     Running   0          7h3m
gateway-5b5c8697f4-jpb4q             2/2     Running   0          7h3m
```

When I send a request to **http://master.code/version**(the gateway created for codemaster service) it always goes to the correct subset.
But when I send a request via spring-boot gateway (http://gateway.code/codemaster/version) request doesn't go to subset v1 only, requests go in round-robin to all the 3 pods. This is what I see in **Kiali**,

[image: Request Routing in Kiali]

[image]

I want to apply traffic shifting between the gateway and other services.

Comment: is istio installed in the code namespace?

Comment: No. Istio installed in Istio-system namespace.

Comment: can you try creating the gateway, virtualservice and destination rules spec in istio-system namespace rather than creating in code namespace

Comment: It not working.

Comment: Hi @Keaz, did below answer help You fix your problem or You still need help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Istio relies on the Host header of a request to apply the traffic rules. Since you are using spring boot gateway to make the request ribbon hits the pod IP directly instead of hitting the service. So to avoid it provide static server list to the

> route /version as http://master.code.cluster.local

in your spring boot gateway config -> to avoid ribbon dynamic endpoint discovery. This should fix the problem.

Comment: No It did not work. As I know there is no CNI in Docker for Mac k8s. Because of that traffic shifting doesn't not work on Docker for Mac K8s

Answer (score 0):

After doing some search I found that there is no CNI in Docker for Mac k8s. Because of that traffic shifting doesn't not work on Docker for Mac K8s